# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Spec<any, never>'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo

I'm getting the above mentioned error on `items: { $splice: [[[index], 1]] }`.

[image]

How do I resolve this?

My partial repo: https://github.com/TheoMer/next_apollo

Comment: try ``index as any``

Comment: Setting index: any give me the following error:

Type '[any]' is not assignable to type 'Spec<any, never>'.
  Type '[any]' is not assignable to type '{ [x: string]: Spec<any, never>; }'.
    Index signature is missing in type '[any]'.ts(2322)

Comment: tried [[index] as any,1]?

Comment: @ShivamPandey That did the trick Many thanks.

Comment: Adding it as ans @TheoG considering accepting it as ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make [index] as any to remove the type error.

`[[index] as any,1]`